# Minecraft LAN World - 2 Users 1 Account (1.8 New Launcher)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Me and my brother have always shared a Minecraft account, and we recently got a new laptop and want to play on a LAN world together.

Comment: Then buy another account.

Comment: Quite sure it's against the Terms and Conditions of making an account to allow multiple people to play through a single account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you can't, because since you are on the same account you can not see each other. You need to get another account in order to play with each other.

Comment: Some people have managed to do it, but it was on an older launcher. Is there a way to do it on the new one/

Comment: I've seen some people do it but it was on an older launcher. Has anyone figured out away to do it on the new 1.8 launcher? Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Setting the compatibilitymode to "Windows XP(service pack 2)" forces the old launcher to be activated. See also https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374954/how-do-i-change-my-minecraft-displayname