# How do I change my Minecraft "displayName"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to host a Minecraft 1.2.5 LAN server with offline mode, and as expected I'm having the issue where everyone who tries to join the server is given the name "Player" so only 1 person can connect.

All the solutions posted here and elsewhere indicate to change the value of `displayName`  in `launcher_profiles.json` ([example 1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334430), [example 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/148410)). However, no such field exists for me (in August 2020). The closest I can find is a `username` field which holds my email address.

What is the proper way in 2020 to override the `displayName` so that multiple players can join this offline server?

Comment: Many optional fields will be absent in .json files if undefined/default - you can add them, following proper JSON formatting. I'm not sure if displayName is one of these but you might try adding it.

Answer (score 4):

I found a workaround for this!!!
You have to use the old version of the launcher for this to work again. To do this, go to the minecraft launcher and right click to go to properties, then go to compatability mode and use Windows XP(service pack 2). Once you set this open the launcher. It will give you a message asking if you want to keep the compatibility settings. Choose yes, (its the option on the right for me). Close the launcher, edit the launcher_profiles.json and open the launcher again. It worked for me, even with new versions. Hope it helps you too :)

Comment: this didn't work for me can u show a video of you doing it